# Error when Refreshing Power BI Gateway - Mashup error

Tags: powerbi, refresh, gateway, azure-analysis-services, mashup

I have been experiencing a periodic **refresh issue** with multiple BI reports currently sitting on service. These are using gateways to pull data from either/or Analysis services or via a direct SQL query of one of our Azure dbs. The error is **sporadic** and has no pattern. the error message also doesn't indicate much as on each failure it quote a different table and then a few days later it works just fine. I am being told **mashup** could be due to too many requests at the same time and it locking me/the report out. but I was wondering if anyone had experienced this before and if they have an **effective fix for this?**

```
Data source error: {"error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError","pbi.error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorCode","detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2147467259"}},{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage","detail":{"type":1,"value":"AnalysisServices: Error del sistema: "}},{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult","detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2147467259"}},{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourceKind","detail":{"type":1,"value":"AnalysisServices"}},{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourcePath","detail":{"type":1,"value":"az-ebpebi01;BIDS_FV_EMA"}},{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Reason","detail":{"type":1,"value":"DataSource.Error"}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}} Table: Fact_Demand_Site_Forecast.
Cluster URI: WABI-NORTH-EUROPE-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Activity ID: 0611a12c-4541-48a2-b029-87fd385c1f09
Request ID: fdd1ad40-d4ca-47fe-983c-29b92c447ac9
Time: 2024-03-11 12:21:37Z
```

I am working on a Power BI Pro account and have full access to all the dbs and cubes. All the code works as like i said, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. it also seems to be days where it works fine for every report (currently 18 of them on the go) and yet other days they all fail to refresh. I can refresh them fine in offline in Power BI Desktop however its only the schedules refreshes which have issues. I have also staggered my refreshes so they don't all happen at the same time and no change. they could work in the morning but then fail in the afternoon.

This has been an ongoing issue for the last 18 months